# Connect Lynxmotion AL5d arm to ROS

Tags: ros, joints, jointstate

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to connect with a Lynxmotion AL5d arm to ROS using an SSC32 servo controller (https://github.com/smd-ros-devel/lynxmotion_ssc32). I realize that I need to publish joint trajectories to do this, but am uncertain about how exactly to approach this. Any recommendations or links to tutorials that do something similar would be greatly appreciated.

http://www.lynxmotion.com/c-130-al5d.aspx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211557/connect-lynxmotion-al5d-arm-to-ros/) by [geffermeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22612/geffermeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used the SSC32 servo driver (my own fork) paired with the [description](https://github.com/tonybaltovski/lynxmotion) and this [script](https://github.com/mars-uoit/ams/blob/indigo-devel/ams_lwms/scripts/al5d_manipulation.py).

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2015-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [geffermeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22612/geffermeng/) on 2015-06-26**:
Thanks very much. I have found this very helpful. I was able to write a new joint command publisher that is working well. Now moving on to think about setting poses, which I can see from your code yo have done too.

**Comment by [geffermeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22612/geffermeng/) on 2015-07-16**:
I am wondering if you might know how to add the AL5d gripper to the URDF. I have had some success with altering the URDF to add a gripper, but I can't replicate the motion properly. In particular, the gripper seems to act like a prismatic joint, when it is fact revolute. Not sure how to model this.

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2015-07-17**:
I have not yet got to there.  I did get some new meshes for the arm but haven't got around to adding them to the URDF (They are on a remote offline machine).  Look at the phantom pincher, which has a similar mechanism.

**Comment by [geffermeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/22612/geffermeng/) on 2015-07-20**:
Great, thank you. I will look into the Phantom Pincher.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-02-01**:
guys i wana control mt Lynxmotion AL5D with ROS may u help me ?